# Z-index not works as per expected between absolute and relative elements

Tags: css

I am trying to keep red line behind the letters. but not works. added more different z-index values. still not works. here the line positioned as absolute, and letter are in relative.

Is there any way to handle this?

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

div.line{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  border-top:1px solid red;
  top:10px;
  z-index:1;
}

.wrap{
  display:flex;
  background:green;
  width:100%;
}

.wrap > div {
  flex:1;
  z-index:50;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>1111111</div>
    <div>22222222</div>
    <div>33333333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you want line in each letters down separtely?

Comment: Add expected output screenshot

Comment: Actually tell us what is purpose? According your DOM structure if red line go under text means it will go under green background because red line div and green background are sibling. If go under green background then red line will be not visible anymore, so what you want?

Comment: @Hanif - I am trying to make my line between green and text. i would like to keep the line right behind the letters.

Comment: your code is working fine, the line is behind the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
}

.parent .line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap>div {
  flex: 1;
  z-index: 5;
}

.wrap>div span{
  background: green;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div><span>1111111</span></div>
    <div><span>22222222</span></div>
    <div><span>33333333</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Text underline</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p style="text-decoration: underline;">This text will be underlined.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

You could try this piece of code which has inline css at the most basic level .

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (`position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `border` to pseudo element

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
}

.wrap > div {
  flex:1;
  z-index:50;
  position:relative;
}
.wrap > div:after{
    height: 3px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    width:95%;
    margin-right:5%;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 3px #fff;
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>1111111</div>
  <div>22222222</div>
  <div>33333333</div>
  </div>
</div>
```